# How to properly set auth_type parameter on AddFacebook AspNetCore authentication scheme?

Tags: asp.net-core

To force users (that has been already authenticated) on your website through Facebook provider to *re-authenticate* them every time, we need to provide as a query string parameter like `auth_type=reauthenticate`.

note: The same behavior for Google is possible simply by setting up `SetParameter("prompt", "consent")` on `AuthenticationProperties` object, but for Facebook, it´s not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to handle the parameter yourself.
First we add the parameter when issuing the challenge:

```cs
var props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = "/"
};
props.SetParameter("AuthType", "reauthenticate");
return Challenge(props);
```

Then we define a callback function that is called before the redirect:

```cs
.AddFacebook(o =>
{
    o.AppId = "app-id";
    o.AppSecret = "app-secret";
    o.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Properties.Parameters.TryGetValue("AuthType", out object authTypeObj) && authTypeObj is string authType)
            {
                ctx.RedirectUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(ctx.RedirectUri, "auth_type", authType);
            }

            ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Note that we have to issue the redirect at the end.
The default handler does that,
but defining our own handler overrides it.